# Google app engine images API - get image size

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, upload

How can I get the size of an image transformed with the app engine images API?

Note: I mean the size in bytes, not the dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`execute_transforms`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html#Image_execute_transforms) returns a `str` (bytestring), so you can just call `len(image_str)`.